# Networking bug in sdlquake?

Tags: linux, networking, sdl, strace, quake

I'm trying to debug an issue with SDL quake. When trying to connect to a quake server over tcp/ip, I enter the ip address then press enter. The machine hangs, and I am unable to exit, change ttys, or run commands while connected via ssh. I ran strace to see what was going on, and here is the last output:

```
getsockname(5, {sa_family=AF_INET, sin_port=htons(2049), sin_addr=inet_addr("0.0.0.0")}, [16]) = 0 
setsockopt(5, SOL_SOCKET, SO_BROADCAST, [1], 4) = 0 
sendto(5, "\200\0\0\f\2QUAKE\0\3", 12, 0, {sa_family=AF_INET, sin_port=htons(26000), sin_addr=inet_addr("255.255.255.255")}, 16) = 12
recvfrom(5,
```

And then the system hangs. SDLquake runs great besides that. Running svgalib as the video driver.

Running Debian 4.0. (I know, I know. It's old. Quake 1 is old too.)

Using sdl quake source found here:
http://www.libsdl.org/projects/quake/

Comment: Or if someone can help me get setup with gdb to start debugging this, that would be awesome. Another clue I realized: sdlquake has to run with setuid root, so perhaps that is what is causing the entire system to crash. Also: after the crash, the system still responds to the SysRq reisub trick.